# How SSH encrypts communications, when using password-based authentication?

Tags: linux, security, unix, encryption, ssh

To my understanding, When using SSH with key-based authentication, the server sends a challenge string to the client and client encrypts it with a private key and sends it back to the server, which decrypts it with the public key and ... :

[image]

But, how does SSH encrypt communications, when we are using password-based authentication? i.e. how does it generate the key(s) to encrypt the data going from client to server and vice versa?

Comment: A nicely illustrated Q, b tu StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be** appropriate for [su], but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter well after a second look, it seems my question wasn't very well illustrated :)   
my real question is how SSH encrypts the communications between client and server, as there is no public-private key pair to use for that purpose ...

Comment: There *is* a public-private keypair, and it's generated on the fly just to secure that session. Each side generates their DH or ECDH keypair and then sends their public key to the peer. Each side may then use a key agreement protocol to derive a common AES key. What's missing is authentication. The peers don't really know if they're talking to each other or a man-in-the-middle. That is where the password comes in. The password is used to authenticate the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you connect through another computer with a password, SSH use a symmetrical encryption:

> Symmetrical encryption is often called shared key or shared secret
>   encryption. There is usually only one key that is used, or sometimes a
>   pair keys where one key can easily be calculated using the other key.
>
> Symmetric keys are used to encrypt the entire communication during a
>   SSH Session. Both the client and the server derive the secret key
>   using an agreed method, and the resultant key is never disclosed to
>   any third party. The process of creating a symmetric key is carried
>   out by a key exchange algorithm. What makes this algorithm
>   particularly secure is the fact that the key is never transmitted
>   between the client and the host. Instead, the two computers share
>   public pieces of data and then manipulate it to independently
>   calculate the secret key. Even if another machine captures the
>   publically shared data, it won’t be able to calculate the key because
>   the key exchange algorithm is not known.
>
> It must be noted, however, that the secret token is specific to each
>   SSH session, and is generated prior to client authentication. Once the
>   key has been generated, all packets moving between the two machines
>   must be encrypted by the private key. This includes the password typed
>   into the console by the user, so credentials are always protected from
>   network packet sniffers.

source: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/ssh-tutorial-how-does-ssh-work

To encrypts the communication, client and server use the Diffie–Hellman key exchange

Here is how the algorithm works at a very basic level:

1. Both the client and the server agree on a very large prime number,
   which of course does not have any factor in common. This prime
   number value is also known as the seed value.
2. Next, the two parties agree on a common encryption mechanism to
   generate another set of values by manipulating the seed values in a
   specific algorithmic manner. These mechanisms, also known as
   encryption generators, perform large operations on the seed. An
   example of such a generator is AES (Advanced Encryption Standard).
3. Both the parties independently generate another prime number. This
   is used as a secret private key for the interaction.
4. This newly generated private key, with the shared number and
   encryption algorithm (e.g. AES), is used to compute a public key
   which is distributed to the other computer.
5. The parties then use their personal private key, the other machine’s
   shared public key and the original prime number to create a final
   shared key. This key is independently computed by both computers but
   will create the same encryption key on both sides.
6. Now that both sides have a shared key, they can symmetrically
   encrypt the entire SSH session. The same key can be used to encrypt
   and decrypt messages (read: section on symmetrical encryption).

Now that the secured symmetrically encrypted session has been established, the user must be authenticated.

Comment: My real question is how SSH encrypts the communications between client and server, as there is no public-private key pair to use for that purpose ... you mentioned client and server generate a shared, could you maybe elaborate how that happens? Thanks

Comment: For the encryption the client and the server use  the Diffie–Hellman key exchange for generate the shared key. ( I'm gonna edit my answer to explain this in detail.)

Comment: If I have a little time, I would make a nice diagram to illustrate all this

Comment: That's really a great answer but this part has got me confused "Even if another machine captures the publically shared data, it won’t be able to calculate the key because the key exchange algorithm is not known." If the key exchange algo. isn't shared b/w the 2 systems how will they decide on an key exchange algo ?

Answer (score 0):

https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#AuthenticationMethods

sshd directly checks the **/etc/passwd** and **/etc/shadow** files if UsePAM in sshd configuration is disabled.

The password is sent through the negotiated encryption, so it is secure from outside parties. ssh authentication with password-based will work depending on you server configuration.